# Data Comparison in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-2010

Since yesterday I've been struggling with thousands of data in Excel. To reduce the amount of data I have, I decided to take the important ones and remove the others. This goes for identical strings with smaller values in this case.

Let's take a 3x2 data:

```
     A      B
  ---------------
1 | ABC123 | 10 |
  ---------------
2 | ABC123 | 50 |
  ---------------
3 | ABC123 | 300 |
  ---------------
```

So as you can see there are three identical strings, yet they all have different values. I just want to compare values between these identical strings, and then keep the string with the biggest value and delete its analogues.

This was just a simple example. There are tons of identical strings in my file which all have different values. And (somehow) the biggest one is the optimal one, so I really don't need the rest of them.

And finally my question is, what am I supposed to do to accomplish this? Any functions, formulas, anything?

I'd really appreciate your help.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also do it by sorting the range by the values(biggest to smallest), then go to the Data Tab, and use 'Remove Duplicates'. Make sure that you have the column selected for the strings when you remove duplicates, and nothing else. Otherwise, you may lose more data than you meant to.

Comment: This is a good option. Requires you to sort so is a bit mor manual but overall far simpler.

Comment: Despite the fact that other answers might also be helpful, I think this one is the easiest one to implement and it totally worked like a charm, thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

Create a pivot table, use your column A as rows, select "max" as the function. Done.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve with an array formula. Array formulas run functions over many cells at a time, returning an array of answers.

Assume on Sheet2 you have a list of all unique string values on column A. On column B, starting wih B1 and dragging down, type:

```
=max(if(sheet1!$A$1:$A$10=A1,sheet1!$B$1:$B$10,""))
```

Confirm this entry by pressing CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER instead of just ENTER.

This checks each row in column A from sheet1. if it matches the unique customer on sheet2 column A, it pulls the column B value in sheet1 for that range. Then it takes the maximum value of all matching results.